# Default value not invoked when using np.select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using np.select to evaluate a few conditions and am trying to assign a deafult value as the previous value of array

For eg if

```
row[i-1] = True
row[i] = NaN
```

then

```
row[i] = True
```

I have used the following lines

```
entry_conditions = [
    (df['Close'] > df['Open'] + 100),
    (df['Close'] < df['Open'] -100)
]

entry_choices = [
    True, False
]

df['entry'] = np.nan
#Need to initialize the column with nan or else it throws an error because evaluating first row triggers default value
df['entry'] = np.select(entry_conditions,entry_choices,default = df['entry'].shift(1))
```

Sample output of df['entry']

```
  True,
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
  True,
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
  True,
```

I don't understand why even after the default value is mentioned, the column still shows nan as final outputs

Sample data obtained by df.to_dict

```
{'Date': {1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:30:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:45:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:15:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:30:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:45:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:15:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:30:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:45:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:15:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:30:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:45:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2021-01-01 13:00:00')},
 'Open': {1: 31376.0,
  2: 31405.0,
  3: 31389.4,
  4: 31377.5,
  5: 31347.8,
  6: 31310.8,
  7: 31343.4,
  8: 31349.5,
  9: 31349.9,
  10: 31325.1,
  11: 31310.9,
  12: 31329.0,
  13: 31376.0,
  14: 31375.5,
  15: 31357.4},
 'High': {1: 31425.0,
  2: 31411.95,
  3: 31389.45,
  4: 31382.0,
  5: 31350.0,
  6: 31354.6,
  7: 31359.0,
  8: 31370.0,
  9: 31364.7,
  10: 31350.0,
  11: 31337.9,
  12: 31378.9,
  13: 31419.5,
  14: 31377.75,
  15: 31360.0},
 'Low': {1: 31367.95,
  2: 31352.5,
  3: 31331.65,
  4: 31301.4,
  5: 31303.05,
  6: 31310.0,
  7: 31325.05,
  8: 31335.35,
  9: 31315.35,
  10: 31281.9,
  11: 31292.0,
  12: 31316.25,
  13: 31352.05,
  14: 31335.0,
  15: 31322.0},
 'Close': {1: 31398.3,
  2: 31386.0,
  3: 31377.0,
  4: 31342.3,
  5: 31311.7,
  6: 31345.0,
  7: 31349.0,
  8: 31344.2,
  9: 31327.6,
  10: 31311.3,
  11: 31325.6,
  12: 31373.0,
  13: 31375.0,
  14: 31357.4,
  15: 31326.0}}
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: default is one value not list of value

Comment: @richardec, Added data to question

Comment: I used your code and my output is `array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])`

Comment: @Corralien, I had modified the conditions because the actual conditions are complex and require 30+ columns. BAsically you got that because you never hit default. Modified the question to now include such cases

Comment: @BENY, Didn't think of it that way. Do you think I can achieve what I want to achieve using numpy and pandas ?